# python pandas compare columns and add list of columns that differ

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare multiple columns in a data frame and add a new column that tells me which columns are different for each row.

for example, for this dataframe i want to compare a1 to a2 and b1 to b2:

```
   a1  b1  a2  b2
0   1   2   1   2
1   1   2   1   3
2   1   2   3   4
```

the output should be something like:

```
   a1  b1  a2  b2  diff
0   1   2   1   2  
1   1   2   1   3  'b1-b2'
2   1   2   3   4  'a1-a2,b1-b2'
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [{'a1': 1, 'b1': 2, 'a2':1, 'b2':2},
        {'a1':1, 'b1': 2, 'a2': 1, 'b2':3},
        {'a1':1, 'b1': 2, 'a2':3 , 'b2':4}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

compare = [('a1','a2'),('b1','b2')]
comp_result = np.array([(df[x[0]] != df[x[1]]) for x in compare])
```

comp_result is a list of lists of True/False values for each of the comparisons but i am not sure how to use that to create the "diff" column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast one-liner without loops:

```py
col_groups = [c.columns for _, c in df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1)]

df['diff'] = pd.Series(np.sum([(df[l] != df[r]).map({True: f'{l}-{r}',False:''}) + ',' for l, r in col_groups], axis=0)).str.strip(',')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   a1  b1  a2  b2         diff
0   1   2   1   2             
1   1   2   1   3        b1-b2
2   1   2   3   4  a1-a2,b1-b2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function `compare_rows` that take each row of the dataframe and uses `compare` to loop through each desired comparison. Using list comprehension, keep only the different columns for each row and format the output in the desired format using `str.join`. Then you can apply the function to each row using the `.apply` DataFrame method.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [{'a1': 1, 'b1': 2, 'a2':1, 'b2':2},
        {'a1':1, 'b1': 2, 'a2': 1, 'b2':3},
        {'a1':1, 'b1': 2, 'a2':3 , 'b2':4}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
compare = [('a1','a2'),('b1','b2')]

def compare_rows(row):
    differences = ['-'.join(comp)
                   for comp in compare
                   if row[comp[0]] != row[comp[1]]]
    return ','.join(differences)

df['diff'] = df.apply(compare_rows, axis=1)
```